# PowerShell regex to match only the first occurence in each row in a .csv

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

Let's say I have a .csv file that looks a little like that:

```
"first_foo","first_foo"
"first_bar","first_bar"
"second_foo","second_foo"
"second_bar","second_bar"
```

And with a PS script I'd like to make it look like this:

```
"first","first_foo"
"first","first_bar"
"second","second_foo"
"second","second_bar"
```

I was thinking about using something like this:

```
$regex=[regex]"first*";
$regex.Replace('"first_foo","first_foo"',"first",1)
```

But it doesn't work. I'm new to powershell and don't use regex so often so I probably made noob mistakes...
Do you guys have a solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit when you say "it doesn't work?"  What *does* it do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the content have no headers, you can add them at run time. This example replaces col1 values and removes '_foo' or '_bar' from the end of the string:

```
Import-Csv test.csv -Header col1,col2 | Foreach-Object {
    $_.col1 = $_.col1 -replace '(_foo|_bar)$'
        $_
}

col1   col2      
----   ----      
first  first_foo 
first  first_bar 
second second_foo
second second_bar
```